# react native videos in carousel

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-video, react-native-snap-carousel

I have been trying to play single video from a slider containing of multiple videos and images..
What i used and tried is in below.
 **1. react-native-video,  2. react-native-snap-carousel**

**How to pause and play the videos wrapped in horizontal carousel and also which are in vertical FlatList Feeds**

This is my carousel :

```
<View style={styles.sliderImgView}>
     <Carousel
       ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
       data={chordData.images}
       firstItem={0}
       autoplay={autoPlay}
       layout={layout}
       loop={loop}
       renderItem={this._renderItem}
       onSnapToItem={(ind) => this.setState({ activeSlide: ind })}
       loopClonesPerSide={bannersDataLength}
       sliderWidth={SCREEN_WIDTH}
       itemWidth={SCREEN_WIDTH} />
</View>
```

And my _renderItem is here :

```
if (item.mediaType === "image") {
return (
    <View style={[styles.sliderImgView, GlobalStyles.ajCenter]} key={index}>
        <Image source={{ uri: item.imgUrl }} resizeMode={"cover"} style={[styles.sliderImageStyle]} />
    </View>
)
} else {
    return (
        <View style={[styles.sliderImgView, GlobalStyles.ajCenter]} key={index}>
            <Video
                source={{ uri: item.imgUrl }}  // Can be a URL or a local file.
                ref={(ref) => { this.player = ref }}  // Store reference
                resizeMode={"cover"}
                paused={index !== this.state.activeSlide}
                onLoad={this.onVideoLoad}
                onError={this.onVideoError}
                controls={false}
                style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

And my Array look's like this :

```
result: [
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Feed Title",
    description: "Feed description....",
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            mediaType: "image",
            imgUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473177027534-53d906e9abcf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            mediaType: "video",
            imgUrl: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            mediaType: "image",
            imgUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473177027534-53d906e9abcf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            mediaType: "video",
            imgUrl: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        },
    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    title: "Feed Title",
    description: "Feed description....",
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            mediaType: "image",
            imgUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587269012604-b20cfbca7b16?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=849&q=80"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: 3,
    title: "Feed Title",
    description: "Feed description....",
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            mediaType: "image",
            imgUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1473177027534-53d906e9abcf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1049&q=80"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            mediaType: "video",
            imgUrl: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
        },

    ]
},
{
    id: 4,
    title: "Feed Title",
    description: "Feed description....",
    data: [
        {
            id: 1,
            mediaType: "image",
            imgUrl: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584679109597-c656b19974c9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I don't want to show the player control that's why i hide it.. just like Instagram.
I don't know whether i should use [this](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-inviewport) or not.

**Present issue is: i should only play the video which is in visible section of user eyes which is in FlatList (i had't mention my flatList code as it is just list_design). i had scroll list with multiple objects with media data in arrays.**  how can i manage to stop playing id number 1 object of data array with id 2 or 4 active video index when other id number 3's media is in active.

[image]

I just want to achieve same as like Instagram post with no performance lagging issues.
can anyone please suggest or help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below did the **magic** controlling other feed's post media sliders to pause the video.

Add the below two props to your FlatList to get the current visible Index., and when ever the current visible index value changes update in componentDidUpdate and call your videoLoad method.

```
viewabilityConfig={{viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 200}}
onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}

onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
   if (viewableItems && viewableItems.length > 0) {
        this.setState({ currentVisibleIndex: viewableItems[0].index });
   }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
   if (prevProps.currentVisibleIndex !== this.props.currentVisibleIndex) {
         this.setState({ currentVisibleIndex: this.props.currentVisibleIndex }, () => {
            this.onVideoLoad();
         })
         //console.log("Check prevProps: " + prevProps.currentVisibleIndex + "----> Check pevState: " + prevState.currentVisibleIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you please paste the full code snippet, I'm also trying to implement almost the same feature. It would be very grateful, please help me

Comment: Basically, I want to like this in this example https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/privileged-pizza but with the video instead of an image

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is using inviewport

Comment: View port basically defines the area of the screen that is visible at that particular moment during the scrolling, so to achieve what you are trying to do, the best way would be to use or create a component that is viewport aware, that way you can play or pause the video depending on the visibility of the component. See snack https://snack.expo.io/6rX_nhFyp

Answer (score 0):

For the above answer **viewabilityConfig and onViewableItemsChanged**
These props works for flatlist but react-native-snap-carousel the props (viewabilityConfig and onViewableItemsChanged) are not supported

As name of library suggest it might be only supported to images not video since it renders multiple time for loop